# Change div height if text overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

I have two `div`s that have some text in them. If I reduce the window, the text of one `div` will overflow. How can I change both `div`s' height if text overflows using JavaScript/jQuery?

Sample screenshot:

[image: example]

HTML:

```
<div id = "creators" class = "big-part">
            <h3>Creators</h3>
            <div class = "creator_name">
                <h4>FlipFloop</h4>
                <p>FlipFloop is a <span id = "flip_age">14</span>&nbsp;year-old boy. He is French and American and is the original creator of Altrifi.
                FlipFloop programs in JavaScript, HTML, CSS and jQuery. He uses AngularJs, ProcessingJs and Bootstrap. FlipFloop is good in math, and he loves putting easter eggs, 
                secret messages and trying out new animations in his webpages.</p>
            </div>
            <div class = "creator_name">
                <h4>TickTock</h4>
                <p>TickTock is FlipFloop's brother. He is 13 and is also French and American. TickTock programs in Javascript, HTML and CSS. He uses the ProcessingJs library.</p>
            </div>
            <!--<div class = "creator_name">
                <h4>Name</h4>
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>-->
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.creator_name {
    width: 35%;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2% 2%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: It works? https://jsfiddle.net/5rgwmsoc/1/

Comment: Works for me in the Fiddle @k97513 provided.

Comment: both div's arent same height

Comment: i think the problem in the parent height ... if the parent isn't specified it will work and of not ,, sorry it will fail

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using a constant height for the text.

Just set height:200px or more so that your text will fit

Answer (score -1):

You don't need JavaScript, CSS only `word-break: break-all;`:

```html
<div style="word-break: break-all;">asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd </div>
```

---

By the way your code does work (however it does not look like the screenshot, I guess you are missing something)

```css
.creator_name {
  width: 35%;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2% 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="creators" class="big-part">
  <h3>Creators</h3>
  <div class="creator_name">
    <h4>FlipFloop</h4>
    <p>FlipFloop is a <span id="flip_age">14</span>&nbsp;year-old boy. He is French and American and is the original creator of Altrifi. FlipFloop programs in JavaScript, HTML, CSS and jQuery. He uses AngularJs, ProcessingJs and Bootstrap. FlipFloop is good
      in math, and he loves putting easter eggs, secret messages and trying out new animations in his webpages.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="creator_name">
    <h4>TickTock</h4>
    <p>TickTock is FlipFloop's brother. He is 13 and is also French and American. TickTock programs in Javascript, HTML and CSS. He uses the ProcessingJs library.</p>
  </div>
  <!--<div class = "creator_name">
                <h4>Name</h4>
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>-->
</div>
```